# Como abrir uma página de acordo com o link inserido no input?

Tags: javascript, html

Quero fazer um formulário que quando eu colocasse o endereço (URL) em um campo e clicar no botão <kbd>Enviar</kbd> ir para o site inserido no campo. Como fazer isso?

Comment: Ao invés de mudar o título da pergunta, marque uma resposta como correta. Aqui não é um fórum.

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Comment: Não coloque resolvido no titulo, o sistema tem checagem de resolvido proprio, somos um Q&A, basta marcar a resposta que lhe resolveu o problema como correta.

Comment: Eita, three-hit-combo.

Comment: @Renan e eu sempre como *"Rubinho"*, sempre fico por ultimo.

Comment: Calma feras... Desculpem aí!
Precisa de tudo isso não..

Comment: Não foi de proposito Thiago, foi que todo mundo comentou ao mesmo tempo, mas o @Renan deve ser o *Barry Allen*, por um milionésimo de segundo o comentário dele chegou primeiro.

Comment: Não tenho costume de utilizar este site. Quando vocês visualizarem um erro, apenas o indique por favor!
Desnecessário.

Comment: @Thiago não foi de proposito, o pessoal só tava te orientando, não precisa se aborrecer, ninguem tá puxando tua orelha, só estão te explicando, não tem nada de desnecessário.

Comment: "Quando vocês visualizarem um erro, apenas o indique por favor! " Foi o que eles fizeram ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utiliza javascript com  `window.open` ou `window.location` para fazer o que deseja.

**Exemplo com window.open():**

Ele vai abrir o url numa nova janela.

`window.open('http://www.google.com');`

**Exemplo com window.location.href:**

Ele vai abrir na janela atual

`window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';`

---

Exemplo de utilização:

```
 <form>
    <input name="url" type="text" id="url"> 
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Acessar" onClick="javascript: window.open(document.getElementById('url').value);" />
 </form>
```

O `javascript` pega o link digitado no campo de texto com ID url, e abre uma nova aba ou janela com `window.open`.

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo

```js
document.getElementById('send').onclick = function(){
  let url = document.getElementById("url").value
  alert(url)
  window.open(url, "_self")
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="url">

<button id="send">Enviar</button>
```